# Fine structure of chlorine - energy levels and total angular momentum $J$

Tags: angular-momentum, atomic-physics, orbitals

The table below summarizes the energy levels of neutral chlorine with fine structure.

I know that lower values of $J = L + S$ should be associated to lower energies. This is confirmed by the intuition that lower values of $J$ mean that the orbital angular momentum $(L)$ and spin $(S)$ don't agree, and this situation is associated to lower energy, even classically.

**Question:** why are lower energies associated to higher values of $J$ in this table? Is there some convention I am missing?

[image]

I found the table here: https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Handbook/Tables/chlorinetable5.htm